# Zero restrictions and product of Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Suppose there are three matrices $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, full rank. Suppose any entries of A is different from zero. Suppose $A$ and $C$ to be positive definite and symmetric.

Suppose the matrix $C$ is the following product: $C=BAB'$

Moreover, $C$ can be partitioned as follows: *(for some $m<n$)*

$C=\begin{pmatrix}C_{11} & 0_{m\times m} \\ 0_{(n-m)\times(n-m)}  &  C_{22} \end{pmatrix}$

that is, for some $m$, the off-diagonal (wrt the partition) blocks are null, and $C_{11}$ is a $(n-m)\times m$ matrix, $C_{22}$ is a $m \times (n-m)$.

Can we retrieve any info or infer any (non-trivial and sharp) restrictions on the matrix $B$?

*[through any decomposition or treating $B$ as unknown,...] Thank you in advance!*

Comment: From the decomposition of $C$, isn't always $n=2m$ ?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typos, now corrected the notation

Comment: if it helps, you can impose the restriction (but it is not a necessary condition)

Comment: You have (trivial) restrictions on $B$ of the form $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} B_{ai} A_{ij} B_{bj} = 0$ for indices $a,b$ chosen such that $C_{ab} = 0$. You could collect all of these and try to write them down in different ways.